# improve the speed of calculation of a C program

Tags: c

I have the following problem:

Given 2 files of N numbers like

file1.dat: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0

file2.dat: 2,5,4,7,6,9,8,1,0,3

I want to know how many time the order of two consecutive numbers in the first file has changed in the second (that contain the same numbers). For example, in file one we start looking for 1 and 2, in the second file 2 come before the 1, so there was a change of the order; in the first file there is 9 and then 0, in the second this order is maintained.

I wrote the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 32421

int main () {
  int A[N], B[N];
  int i,j,k=0,count=0;
  FILE *fp;

  if ((fp = fopen ("file1.dat", "r")) == NULL) {
    printf ("Error opening file 1\n");
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    fscanf (fp, "%d", &A[i]);
  fclose (fp);

  if ((fp = fopen ("file2.dat", "r")) == NULL) {
    printf ("Error opening file 2\n");
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    fscanf (fp, "%d", &B[i]);
  fclose (fp);

  for(i=0; i<N-1; i++)
    for(j=0; j<N; j++)
      for(k=0 ; k<N; k++)
        if(B[j]==A[i] && B[k]==A[i+1] && k < j )
    count++;


  printf("The number of inversion is: %d\n",count);

  return 0;
}
```

The files with which I'm dealing are very big as you can see from the 3rd line of the program (32421 numbers for each file), so the time taken is too big. Anyone have any suggestion to improve the speed of calculation?

---

I tried also with the break adding in the loops in the following way:

```
 int a;  

  for(i=0;i<N-1;i++){ 
    a=0;
    for(j=0;j<N;j++){
      for(k=0;k<N;k++){
    if(A[i]==B[j] && A[i+1]==B[k] && k<j) {
      count++;
      break;
      a=1;
    } if(A[i]==B[j] && A[i+1]==B[k] && j<k){
      break;
      a=1;
    }
      }
      if(a==1){
      break;
      }
    }
  }
```

But it still takes more than 5 hours. How can I speed this up?

Comment: Are all the numbers distinct?

Comment: You can probably do some `break`ing in your loops

Comment: @pmg, the break could be a solution, but I don't know how to write them in the program. The numbers are all distinct

Comment: I'm rusty with C... but how is `fscanf` ignoring the `,`. Does it do that automatically?

Answer (score 4):

```
for(i=0; i<N-1; i++) {
    //looking for the position of B[i] in A
    j=-1;
    while ( A[++j] != B[i] ) {}

    //now A[j] is B[i]

    for (k= 0 ; k < j; k++) {
        //is the next in B in a previous position in A ?
        if (B[i+1] == A[k]) {
            count++;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

And also, here's another solution

```
int pos1, pos2;
for(i=0; i<N-1; i++) {
    pos2=-1;
    for(j=-1; j<N && pos1 != -1 && pos2 != -1; j++) { //will stop if both are found
       if (pos1 == -1 && B[i]==A[j]) pos1 = j; //found the position of a num
       if (B[i+1]==A[j]) pos2 = j; //found the position of the next num
       if (pos2 < pos1) {
          count++;
       }
    }
    pos1 = pos2; //useful for next loop..
}
```

Comment: Nice. You can also look for (B[i+1] == A[k]) with k starting at N and stopping at k>j when j gets close to N.

Comment: @pfnuesel Yep indeed that's a way to improve it :)

Comment: The second script doesn't work. The j loop won't start because pos2 start with -1. I've been testing the first one and unfortunately it doesn t work (yesterday night I've tried but the dataset I used wasn't correct, today I used the correct one but it still employs more than 1 hour to give me the result). :S

Answer (score 1):

The key here is "two *consecutive* numbers in the first file".

There is no need to do an O(N^2) loop.  In fact, you can use a dynamic programming approach utilizing the following criteria:

- The numbers are distinct
- For any set of `N` numbers, the number values are `0..N-1` (this is my assumption)
- For any two consecutive numbers `A` and `B` in the first file, order is preserved in the second file if you have already encountered `A` at the time you encounter `B`.

Note my assumption about values.  If that assumption is false, then you may as well use the O(N^2)-ish answer that is currently accepted (although you could build a tree to index values and the worst-case becomes O(N.log(N)).

If you can index the values directly, then this problem becomes linear.

Comment: But how should I modify my cicle?

Comment: What do you mean by 'cicle'?

Comment: sorry, I made a bad translation. I meant loop

Comment: My proposal involves reading and storing your arrays in a different way.  When you read the first array, you store information about it (that is, for any one number you might store the valud of its neighbour instead of actually storing the list verbatim).  You then count inversions at the same time as you read the second array, but don't store the second array.  This approach is highly specialised to the problem, and relies on some simple assumptions about the input (namely that all values in the first file are present in the second file, albeit in a different arrangement).

Comment: You can actually enforce this last assumption by filtering A as a first step in `O(N.log(N))` or linearly if the values can be indexed directly.

Answer (score 0):

The number of inversions between two arrays of length N is ...

if N is 1, the number of inversions is 0
otherwise, it is the number of inversions between the last N-1 elements of the first array and the second array excluding the first element of the first array plus the position of the first element of the first array in the second array

Hooray for recursion :)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static int find(int a, int *b, size_t n) {
  size_t k = 0;
  while (k < n) {
    if (b[k] == a) return k;
    k++;
  }
  return -1;
}

int ninversions(int *a, int *b, size_t n) {
  if (n == 1) return 0;
  size_t pos = find(*a, b, n);
  if (pos == (size_t)-1) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  int *newb = malloc((n - 1) * sizeof *newb);
  memcpy(newb, b, pos * sizeof *b);
  memcpy(newb + pos, b + pos + 1, (n - pos - 1) * sizeof *b);
  int retval = pos + ninversions(a + 1, newb, n - 1);
  free(newb);
  return retval;
}
```